# How to get Ubuntu 15.04 running full-screen on VMware?

Tags: vmware

How can I change the screen resolution in a VMware Virtual Machine running Ubuntu to be able to view it in full-screen?

Comment: Your title is really confusing. Are you asking how to install Ubuntu in VMWare in the first place, or do you just need to know how to make it fullscreen?

Comment: If the above still won't work try to increase the video card memory in VM settings. It worked for me.

Comment: No answer did work for me, I still see the console confined into a small box with long black margins inside VMware. Is there an updated solution for this?

Answer (score 9):

It will work best, if you install the VMWare Tools.
There is a kb article for you: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1022525

This will enable some features like shared clipboard.

Answer (score 7):

In the newer vmware versions goto `view-> autosize-> autofit` guest and in older versions `go to view and press "Switch to scale mode`" which will adjust the virtual screen when you adjust the application.

Hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 5):

To view Ubuntu in fullscreen inside VMware, follow these steps after enabling 3D acceleration in VMware:

1. [Install](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1022525) VMware tools in Ubuntu to enable dynamic screen re-sizing
2. Change the display option to "Automatic/host screen"
3. `Ctrl+Alt+Enter` to enable/disable full-screen mode.

Comment: You need to restart VM in order that to take effect

Answer (score 4):

Just Install VMware Tool using `sudo apt install open-vm-tools` this will enable you clipboard copy paste, full screen and lots of features.

Comment: This is also described in [VMware KB](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2073803) and [Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Tools#Installing_VMware_tools_on_an_Ubuntu_guest).

Comment: This helped me obtaining auto resize screen but not shared clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings->Display->Choose a 16:9 aspect ratio. Done.
You can choose the optimal resolution as well to get best out of your monitor/screen.

Answer (score 0):

1. install vmware tools: `sudo ./vmware-install.pl -d`
2. `settings` - `Devices` - `Displays` - `Resolution` select it, and move dialog box to right: click `applay`.

[settings image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IdLN.png)

Answer (score 0):

After "ctrl + alt + enter", just 3 steps.
1 step, find&click "View" menu on menu bar.
2 step, find&click "Autosize" menu
3 setp, find&click "Stretch guest" menu.

so u will see full screen.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Devices --> click on "Insert Guest Additions CD image.."
after clicking on this, you will see one CD ROM in dock options. Click on it and run software. Restart the machine after installation.
If it doesn't work, open terminal and type

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

after this command try to install CD image again and it will work.

2nd option, Go to terminal and type

```
xrandr
```

select your screen size by

```
xrandr -s "available size"
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the Ubuntu VM in VMware workstation 11, go to Display setting, over there change the Resolution option to 1280 x 800 (16:10), by default its 800 x 600 (4:3).

Hope this helps,

Regards,
Deepu KG

Comment: Not sure if running 1280x800 will equate to "full screen" on their display ...